# Python generates corrupt excel file with .insert_bitmap

Tags: python, excel, bitmap, xlwt

My code gives me a corrupted .xls file, and i don't know why; it only happens when I try to insert a bitmap (sheet1.insert_bitmap(r"bmp.bmp", 0, 0))
What could be the problem?

```
import xlwt

book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet1 = book.add_sheet("error")
sheet1.insert_bitmap(r"bmp.bmp", 0, 0)
book.save("error.xls")
```

Edit2: I put the created file in a shared folder, and 2 out of 5 computers opened it in protected view, the other 3 opened it normally. All the computers used Excel 2010.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I meant, [Color_depth](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth)

Comment: I do not understand how this should help me, could you please be more specific, or modify my code so that it works?

Comment: You are using `xls`, a outdated File Format. It's likely that the Images Color Format couldn't handle properly either by `xlwt` or Excel. Do you really **need** `xls` couldn't you use `xlsx`?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I only used xlwt because i found it easier as a beginner. I already made an excel design for printing so keeping xlwt would be nice, but if it doesn't work then I'll just redo it. Thank you!

Comment: Read about `openpyxl`, [Inserting an image](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html?highlight=image#inserting-an-image)